# Using Bulk collect in PL/SQL into table object type

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Can somebody tell me why I am getting PL/SQL errors while compiling the procedure:

> Error(11,23): PLS-00403: expression 'USER_DETAILS_LIST' cannot be used as an INTO-target of a SELECT/FETCH statement.

Here are the objects and the procedure :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE  USERID IS OBJECT
(
 USERID             VARCHAR2(50)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE  USERID_LIST AS TABLE OF  USERID;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE  USER_DETAILS IS OBJECT
(
 USERID             VARCHAR2(50),
 ORGANIZATION       VARCHAR2(200),
 EMAIL              VARCHAR2(200),
 FIRSTNAME          VARCHAR2(200),
 LASTNAME           VARCHAR2(200),
 FULLNAME           VARCHAR2(200)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE  USER_DETAILS_LIST AS TABLE OF  USER_DETAILS;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_USER_DETAILS_FOR_NOTIF(USERID_LIST IN USERID_LIST,
    USER_DETAILS_LIST IN  USER_DETAILS_LIST) IS

BEGIN
    SELECT  USER_DETAILS(USER_ID,
                         ORGANIZATION,
                         EMAIL,
                         FIRSTNAME,
                         LASTNAME,
                         FULLNAME)
            BULK COLLECT INTO USER_DETAILS_LIST
            FROM    USERS_TBL
            WHERE   USER_ID IN (SELECT USERID
                                  FROM TABLE( USERID_LIST));
END;
```

Comment: Not the source of your error...  But having a collection type name match the name of a local variable (or parameter) of that type seems highly likely to lead to confusion.

Comment: Thanks for noticing that, I will fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the procedure signature, `USER_DETAILS_LIST` needs to be specified as `IN OUT` instead of `IN`, as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_USER_DETAILS_FOR_NOTIF(USERID_LIST IN USERID_LIST,
    USER_DETAILS_LIST IN OUT USER_DETAILS_LIST)
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks Khalid, what a catch :-)

Comment: Hi Khalid, can you please look at the sub query in the above SQL, it is selecting all the userid in the userid_list collection. The issue is this procedure is not returning the collection for all the userids I pass as an input. That makes me believe that "SELECT USERID
                                  FROM TABLE( USERID_LIST)" sub query is not returning all the users.